# So far I (haven't)?

Tags: grammaticality

Can you please tell me if this sentence is correct?

> I lay on the bed and let myself relax a little. It was my first day as a fugitive and so far, I *haven’t* done anything that might be considered a screw up.

It's the "haven't" part that I think might be wrong.

Comment: Your problem is that the first sentence and the second sentence's introductory clause are past tense, then "so far" slips into present tense.

Answer (score 1):

The ‘haven’t needs to changed to ‘hadn’t’. Then your sentence works. You are then, in the future from the moment being described - looking back on it.